# Bash cat/echo creating different files

Tags: bash

For specific reasons, I'm trying to create a second file identical to the first one without using `cp` by using `cat` and `echo`

My current bash code is

```
contents=$(cat file1)
echo $contents > file2
```

and I have the diff here

https://www.diffchecker.com/UIbkWHi5

The differences have to do with spaces/newlines, and I've played around with some `echo` flags (namely `-n` and `-e`) to no avail. Where can I go from here?

Comment: `echo "$contents"` -- quotes matter. Or even better, `printf '%s\n' "$contents"`

Comment: To understand the differences that still persist after quoting is fixed (until you switch from `echo` to `printf`), see the excellent answer by Stephane on https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo

Comment: that works, thank you!

Comment: (You can't get an exact byte-for-byte representation read through a command substitution unless you know that your file is a valid UNIX text file, meaning that every line *including the last one* ends with a linefeed, and that the file contains no NUL characters).